# What a half height 5.25" drive bay for?

Tags: desktop, optical-drive, accessories

I bought a case, and it has the standard array of 5.25" 3.5" and a single 2.5" drive bays. It ALSO has a single 5.25" bay, however this bay is about HALF the height of a regular drive bay. What would go in here? The only thing I can think of would be a notebook drive or something, but holding my laptop to it, the drive in my laptop is wider. Is there a name for this odd half-height 5.25" bay?

Here is a listing. It lists the full size bays, but not the smallish one. The very top piece pops out and has brackets to hold something.

http://www.antec.com/product.php?id=704923&fid=4&lan=us

Comment: Can you link to the case?

Comment: ...and/or post a picture of the bay?

Comment: My hunch is that it's for a slim optical (cd/dvd) drive.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's just a slimline 5.25 inch bay, sometimes refered to as a 12.7mm bay; they are mostly for dvd/cd burners like [this one](http://h30094.www3.hp.com/product/sku/3981865/mfg_partno/532068-B21). You can buy adapter products to divide a normal 5.25 inch bay into 2 slimline bays like [this one](http://www.ultradrives.com/product_info.php/products_id/785).

Comment: Some USB/Audio/Firewire, etc port panels are offered in half height (slim)